# jQuery datepicker automatically append second field with first field input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using to datepicker fields, one for a Start date and one for an End date. I have got everything almost working as I require however I am struggling to get the End date field to update automatically when the start date field is selected if I don't have a default date. It work's fine if I have a default date in place but I need it to be blank in this case. I have setup the code on jsFiddle and would be extremely grateful if someone could point out how I can achieve this result.

http://jsfiddle.net/clj83/7TvKr/

Here is the code below which is almost working.

```
$(function(){
var dates = $('#cntnt01cd_fax, #cntnt01cd_telephone').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', changeMonth: false, changeYear: false, numberOfMonths: 3, showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == 'cntnt01cd_fax' ? 'minDate' : 'maxDate';
        var instance = $(this).data('datepicker');
        var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker('option', option, date);
    }
});
});

<div class="form_title">
Start Date
</div>
<div class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="cntnt01cd_fax" name="cntnt01cd_fax" id="cntnt01cd_fax" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</div>

<div class="form_title">
End Date
</div>
<div class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="cntnt01cd_telephone" name="cntnt01cd_telephone"     id="cntnt01cd_telephone" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you want to achieve. Can you describe what you do in steps and then state the desired/current outcome of those steps?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
        $(function() {
            $( "#v_map_1" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "-d",
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                  var d=selectedDate.split("-");
                  var da=d[0];
                  var mo=d[1];
                  var yr=parseInt(d[2])+1;
                  var nd=da+"-"+mo+"-"+yr;
                  $( "#v_map_2" ).datepicker( "setDate", nd );
                 }
            });
            $( "#v_map_2" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
            });
        });
    });
```

Try this
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGd8b/3/)